# Як назвати людину, яка має те саме прізвище?

Tags: вибір-слова, одним-словом

Як назвати людину, яка має те саме прізвище, що і той, хто говорить?
Є слово <sub>рос.</sub> *однофамилец*, і Російсько-український словник фразеологізмів (сталих виразів) [перекладає його так](http://stalivyrazy.org.ua/everyfile.php?transfer=folders/o/odnofamiljx.html):

> *У нього зі мною, у мене з ним те саме (одно, однакове) прізвище; він зі мною, я з ним того самого (одного, однакового) прізвища.*

Ці варіанти виглядають занадто довгими.

В Інтернеті можна часто знайти варваризм *однофамілець*:

> *Його переплутали із загиблим під час Євромайдану **однофамільцем**.* — [UNIAN](https://www.unian.ua/curiosities/1882411-proshu-ne-molitisya-za-upokiy-moeji-dushi-u-lutsku-cholovik-znayshov-svoe-foto-na-stendi-gerojiv-nebesnoji-sotni.html)

…але, наскільки мені відомо, корінь *«фамілія»* використовується в українській мові лише у значенні «сімейство; група людей, об'єднаних родовими зв'язками», а не «прізвище».

Мені відомо про слово *тезка*, яке означає людину, яка має таке само ім'я (як я) і також відомо, що можна сказати *повний тезка*, що означає однакове ім'я і прізвище.

Comment: Відповідь на ваше запитання — «родич». Виправте, будь ласка на «Як назвати людину, яка має ТАКЕ саме прізвище?»

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Дещо додам до попередньої відповіді.
Олександр Пономарів - доктор філологічних наук, професор [відповідає](http://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blogs/2014/07/140704_ponomariv_blog22_ko) на питання чи є в українській мові слово однофамілець:

> *Словники цю лексему фіксують, але вона не належить до активного
>   вжитку. Замість неї краще використовувати тезко, бо це людина не лише
>   з однаковим ім'ям, а й з однаковим прізвищем.*

---

[Словник Лемківської Говірки. Пиртей П.С. 2001](http://i.share.pho.to/045746c2_o.jpeg):

> ***єдноіменник*** -ника, ч. Ол.
>   Тезко; друга особа з тим самим ім'ям.

---

[Зведений словник застарілих та маловживаних слів](http://litopys.org.ua/rizne/zvslovnyk.htm):

> ***Тезоіменитий*** — однойменний, тезка

---

Щодо виразу "подвійний тезка" (за ім'ям і прізвищем або ім'ям та по-батькові) - на жаль, в жодному словнику не знайшлося пояснення, але словосполучення досить [вживане](http://odtrk.km.ua/news/8063-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%97,-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2,-%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%96%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%83,-%D1%8F%D0%BA%D1%96-%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8E%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%97-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%83%D1%82%D1%82%D1%8F.html) як у побутовій так і в літературній мові:

> *Подвійні тезки - Ольги Василівни-товаришують, скільки себе пам’ятають.*

Comment: Доктор філологічних наук Олександр Пономарів, викладач університету, популяризатор правопису.. веде блог "Блог професора Пономарева" і не може вірно перекласти своє власне прізвище, на відміну від батька.
Батько — Д. С. Пономарьов[1] (1908—1943)

Answer (score 11):

[Олександр Авраменко каже](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MQARsP1ctcQ), що ***ОДНОФАМІЛЕЦЬ*** - не суржикове слово і не варваризм.

Це підтверджує стаття [ОДНОФАМІ́ЛЕЦЬ, льця, чол](http://sum.in.ua/s/odnofamilecj) у СУМ.

Походить від латинського ***familia***, як і інші слова з цим же коренем - ***фамільний*** (*альбом*, *срібло* тощо), ***фамільярний***.

Якщо не до вподоби ***однофамілець***, то Олександр Авраменко радить вживати синонім **тезкО** (з наголосом на **О**), а не **тезка**, адже, як стверджує мовознавець, **тезкО** - це людина не лише з однаковим ім'ям, а й з однаковим прізвищем.

Хоча СУМ не дає варіанту значення [ТЕЗКО, а, чол.](http://sum.in.ua/s/tezko) щодо прізвища.

Comment: Додам, що в СУМ-11 також є розмовні [однофамі́льниця](http://sum.in.ua/s/odnofamiljnycja) й [однофамі́льник](http://sum.in.ua/s/odnofamiljnyk).

Comment: Додам, що словник УМІФ містить [і «тезко́», і «те́зка»](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=тезка) — але друге лише жіночого роду.

Comment: Цікаво, дякую. Але у мене залишається підозра, що обґрунтування, яке навів Авраменко, недостатнє. Як я вже писав у запитанні, корінь *фамілія* не використовується у значенні «власна назва родини», а значить, із нього не можна будувати похідні як-то *одно+R+ець*. Абсолютно така само ситуація, як зі словом *язик* у значенні «мова»: якщо воно саме по собі не використовується, то не буває і похідних форм «одно*язичний*, дво*язичний*» тощо. І варіант «те́зка/тезко́» я також розглядав…

Comment: Sasha, одинадцятитомний «Словник української мови» ( або СУМ-11) було видано у 1970 — 1980 роках, там ще багато інших русизмів.

Answer (score -1):

**Людина з однаковим прізвищем**

Російське **"однофамилец" (одна фамилия)** - складене слово, маємо перекладати по частинам. Числівник **"одно"** в значенні **"єдине"** передається так само, до іменника **"фамилец(фамилия)"** є **прямий** український відповідник **"прізвище"**.

То ж **людина з однаковим** (до іншої) **прізвищем**.

Похідні від слова **"фамілія"** можна вжити, якщо **фамільний замок**, **фамільні коштовності** або **фамільну спадщину** в контексті неможливо замінити на іншу конструкцію без використання слова **фамілія** (наприклад, **родинний замок** або **коштовності, що належать роду Ольговичей**).

[**Чому прізвище не фамілія**](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=WPvn13rV0qo&autoplay=1)

Comment: а чому ви перекладаєте з *однофамилец*, а не, наприклад, з *namefellow*?

Comment: Окрім того, запитання містить оцінку перекладу саме з російської, а не будь-якої іншої мови.

Answer (score -1):

*Землянин* - це людина з Землі, а *земляк* - це людина з того ж маленького куточка Землі, що й ти, тому, за аналогією можна **прізвищак**.

Comment: За вашим прикладом росіянин - це людина з Росії, але вони кажуть рюські. А як щодо України, Польщі, Румунії, Греції - ні.